# How to use JavaScript libraries on QML

Tags: javascript, qt, qml

I use some javascript libraries with QML on 5.12.2. Some of them works like Proj4JS. But I get errors when using [geographiclib.js](https://geographiclib.sourceforge.io/scripts/geographiclib.js) library with QML. How can the JavaScript library be imported into QML?

main.qml:

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Window 2.12
import "geographiclib.js" as MyGeo
Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    Component.onCompleted: {
        var Geodesic = MyGeo.GeographicLib.Geodesic,
            DMS = MyGeo.GeographicLib.DMS,
            geod = Geodesic.WGS84;
        var r = geod.Inverse(23, 22, 44, 29);
        console.log("distance is: ", r.s12.toFixed(3) + " m")
    }
}
```

Error:

```
qrc:/geographiclib.js:3081: ReferenceError: window is not defined
qrc:/main.qml:9: TypeError: Cannot read property 'Geodesic' of undefined
```

Comment: Where did you place the .js file (during runtime)? I think it should be attached as resource in .qrc

Comment: The js file is in qrc: `<file>main.qml</file><file>geographiclib.js</file>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way to do this, is to make `GeographicLib` available globally:

At the end of the *geographiclib.js* file, change

```js
window.GeographicLib = geo;
```

to

```js
this.GeographicLib = geo;
```

and then you can just use:

*main.qml:*

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Window 2.12
import "geographiclib.js" as ThenItWillBeAvailableGlobally
Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    Component.onCompleted: {
        var Geodesic = GeographicLib.Geodesic,
            DMS = GeographicLib.DMS,
            geod = Geodesic.WGS84;
        var r = geod.Inverse(23, 22, 44, 29);
        console.log("distance is: ", JSON.stringify(r))
    }
}
```

Resulting in:

```
qml: distance is:  {"lat1":23,"lat2":44,"lon1":22,"lon2":29,"a12":21.754466225665134,"s12":2416081.7576307985,"azi1":13.736139413215236,"azi2":17.669059640534535}
```

---

It you don't want to change the *geographiclib.js* file at all, you could add a global window object using, for example:

*window.js:*

```js
this.window = this;
```

and then use:

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Window 2.12
import "window.js" as ThenWindowWillBeAvailableGlobally
import "geographiclib.js" as ThenGeographicLibWillBeAvailableGlobally
Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    Component.onCompleted: {
        var Geodesic = GeographicLib.Geodesic,
            DMS = GeographicLib.DMS,
            geod = Geodesic.WGS84;
        var r = geod.Inverse(23, 22, 44, 29);
        console.log("distance is: ", JSON.stringify(r))
    }
}
```

---

If you don't want to add any global variables but you are happy to edit the *geographiclib.js* file, then you could just move line 68 to the top of the file:

```js
var GeographicLib = {};
/*
 * Geodesic routines from GeographicLib translated to JavaScript.  See
 * https://geographiclib.sourceforge.io/html/js/
```

and at the end of the file change

```js
  } else {
    /******** otherwise just pollute our global namespace ********/
    window.GeographicLib = geo;
  }
});
```

to

```js
  } else if (typeof window === 'object') {
    /******** otherwise just pollute our global namespace ********/
    window.GeographicLib = geo;
  }
});
```

and then your *main.qml* will work just fine.

Comment: Thank you for the awesome answer! I won't need to start React Native if I keep using npm packages with QML :) I hope the Qt company will add a detailed documentation about this. By the way I was wrong to type the distance, it should be `"distance is: ", r.s12`

Answer (score 1):

You are importing the javascript file correctly.

From the [doc](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-javascript-hostenvironment.html):

> QML provides a JavaScript host environment tailored to writing QML
>   applications. This environment is different from the host environment
>   provided by a browser or a server-side JavaScript environment such as
>   Node.js. For example, **QML does not provide a window object** or DOM
>   API as commonly found in a browser environment.

Comment: I thought with Ecmascript 7 support on 5.12.2, QML might accept window object. The JavaScript library contains window object. Unfortunately I don't know how to fit javascript library for QML. I tried libraries like Qmljsfy (a qml module to convert npm packages to QML javascript files), it didn't work.

Comment: Thanks. I don't get window error but I get `TypeError: Cannot read property 'Geodesic' of undefined`