# Can tensorflow.js be used with QT quick and QML to build native machine learning apps?

Tags: qt, qml, tensorflow.js, qt-quick

I have just started using QT/QML for cross platform app development. I know QML can use JavaScript to handle events (https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-javascript-expressions.html). What I am interested in is using tensorflow.js for handling predictions with QML. This question ([How to use JavaScript libraries on QML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55531885/how-to-use-javascript-libraries-on-qml)) kind of indicates that it should be possible. I am going to give it a try in any case but was curious to know if anyone else has already done that, if so were there any challenges?

Comment: I think this is off topic. Polls should be conducted on Twitter, for example. Try it, and if you get any problems, make a question about it (and maybe even answer it yourself if the challenge is wirth documenting).

Comment: In QML there is a [Canvas](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-canvas.html) class that Provides a 2D canvas item enabling drawing via JavaScrip.
For example, look at this example that uses Chart.js in qml 

https://github.com/MichaelVoelkel/ChartJs2QML

I think you can use it like this.you can also use .js file in QML.